# Kuberenetes 403: Cannot patch pods in the namespace

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, go-micro

While trying to deploy a pod that utilizes the go-micro framework I received the following error:

```
2018/12/27 23:04:51 K8s: request failed with code 403
2018/12/27 23:04:51 K8s: request failed with body:
2018/12/27 23:04:51 {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods \"user-5676b5696-jspp5\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot patch pods in the namespace \"default\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"user-5676b5696-jspp5","kind":"pods"},"code":403}
2018/12/27 23:04:51 K8s: error
```

It seems like go-micro doesn't have the necessary permissions to patch pods from within a pod.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved with creating a cluster role binding that enables the correct permissions

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: micro-rbac
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    # Reference to upper's `metadata.name`
    name: default
    # Reference to upper's `metadata.namespace`
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```